# SSIS and SQL SERVER DATETIME DIFFERENCE

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

what is the difference between ssis datetime and sql server datetime.The sql server 
datetime value (1974-04-01 00:00:00.000) is copied into ssis declared datetime variable and for some reason it is accepting the value as 01/04/1974 00:00:00.000.How to supply ssis variable in sql server variable format?

Comment: I don't think this is a real issue as the underlying date is probably being stored the same way in both cases.  If you want to _present_ a date a certain way, you can use `CONVERT`.

Comment: They are both the same date just in a different format.  You can use SSIS date functions to format if needed.  I recommend you leave it alone until presentment and then use the presentment tool to format the date the way you want it to appear.

Comment: Don't confused the display format if the datetime with the actual value. The value is stored in a native binary format and the tool (SSDT, SSMS, etc.) controls the displayed string format.

Comment: got the point.thank you all